# Check if contact has been changed on android native contacts to update my db (sqlite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im developing a birthday reminder android app. I retrieve all phone contacts and store in sqlite (name, phone, birthdate).

My question is if I can check if user, for example, changes contact name or phone apply this update to my sqlite database.

Do android contacts have any id or something? Thanks!

EDIT: I need to store in a new database table because I have a column 'msg' which sends automatically and SMS if today is someone's birthday.

Comment: Why did you not simply use the contacts DB instead of duplicating those value ? This would remove this problem.

Comment: Hi @AxelH, what do you mean with using contacs BD instead of duplicating those value? I need to store contacts info into db because I have a column 'msg' which automatically sends an SMS with that msg if his/her birthday is today.

Comment: See my answer, there is your answer and a bit more of explanation about my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question, you can see the documentation of the [`Contact Provider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#ContactBasics) to see what is available.

> The ContactsContract.Contacts table also has the column LOOKUP_KEY that is a "permanent" link to the contact row. Because the Contacts Provider maintains contacts automatically, it may change a contact row's _ID value in response to an aggregation or sync. Even If this happens, the content URI CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI combined with contact's LOOKUP_KEY will still point to the contact row, so you can use LOOKUP_KEY to maintain links to "favorite" contacts, and so forth. This column has its own format that is unrelated to the format of the _ID column.

So looking to this LOOKUP_KEY[`LOOKUP_KEY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY)

> An opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact if its row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.

This should be safe to use.

---

But of course, I would see if it would not be easier to store only the ID and the message you want to send. Let the Contact information where there are, and ask the provider the list of contact who are born today to send the message to them. You don't need to synchronize to distinct database with this solution.

Comment: Tbh, it has more sense to store contact id and msg instead of all contact data, and retrieve all info from contactsdb but how is for learn purpose I'll take a look to that lookup_key. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkGonzalez In both case you will need this key, but at least, you don't have to check for update all the time (those are quite rare, so this check will mostly do nothing).

Comment: yeah, I think I'd need contact_id and lookup_id, because i'll use contact_id while lookup_key doesn't tell me that contact_id row has changed.

Comment: @MarkGonzalez I didn't read everything but I think this is not about updated contact information but if the contact ID has changed, no matter why. So îf you use the `LOOKUP`, even if the `CONTACT_ID` changed, you will still find the contact since the `LOOKUP_ID` will be the same for this contact. Do some test to be sure, I don't have a workstation here

Comment: So basically lookup_id will never gonna change even if i change contact's info like name, phones, address, birthdate... Nice, as i said before I'll take a look when I get home. EDIT: But if lookup_id never changes i'll have to check everytime I start app if data from contacts matches mydb data.

Comment: This is explained in the Contentprovider page, yes, just read the first citation I've posted. It explain it better than me. With this, you don't need to worry, it won't change unless the user is delete.